# How do you make M2 Ultra with lithography?

Tags: integrated-circuit, semiconductors, lithography

The M2 Ultra chip is unusual not because it's a single chip made of two halves, but because the halves are *centrosymmetric* images of each other instead of translation. Assuming the wafer is exposed first for the odd-numbered patterns, flipped 180 degrees, then for the even-numbered ones,

1. Can you even do that without a custom machine that does the flipping in the lithography lines?
2. Can you shut down the CO2/ArF laser for 50% of the time with ~1s each time to not expose the opposing patterns during a pass of a wafer?
3. Assuming the newest generation of lithography machines perform as advertised and achieve ~1 nm superimposing accuracy, does that mean it's possible to have transistors instead of just micron-scale wires riding the boundary of 2 different exposures? Theoretically, does this allow exposing the whole wafer as a single monolithic chip with different masks for different regions?

EDIT: After some research, it appears I'm misled by a screenshot of one of Apple's patents here
[image: M1 Ultra]
into thinking that it's something other than 2.5D packaging. Still, my original questions stand.

EDIT2: Let me clarify what I meant by the original question. Suppose I have a wafer with 100 patterns to expose. Is it possible to first expose 1,3,5,...,99, get the wafer out of the lithographer, use a mechanical arm to rotate the whole wafer 180 degrees, send the wafer back into the lithographer, then expose 2,4,6,...,100, such that the adjacent patterns, e.g. 5 and 6, are *centrosymmetric* instead of a simple translation of each other. Note that this would *NOT* need any kind of interposer, change of masks, and the wires could be in say M1 or M2, which means they could be nm in pitch instead of um.

Please note that if you want to make a chip like M2 Ultra, the two halves have to be centrosymmetric.
[image]

Comment: Are the two halves connected via some other layer which covers both halves, or just bond wires?

Comment: Meatball Princess - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that original content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Please can you [edit] your question to add the required source link for the original image? Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't they just make one set of masks that exposes both copies of the chip? That seems much simpler to me.

Answer (score 5):

Source?

I'm pretty sure its just 2x the same chip cleverly connected on the interposer.

It would be insanely more expensive otherwise - you need a complete second set of masks for the mirrored chip, i.e. 2x production cost.

No you cannot add a mirror in the chip production process, that won't work.